# Upload image not working in server - opencart

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, opencart2.x

I have a problem when uploading image in OpenCart 2.0.3.1. When clicking on upload new image button or create new folder button nothing happens.

I downloaded the same code and ran it in my local server, everything is working perfectly here, not in server. I am using Amazon AWS ubuntu 14.
I have set all the file permissions correctly.

[image]

Comment: do you see any error in browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

use $(document).on('click','#button-upload', function() instead of  $('#button-upload').on('click', function() in templates/view/common.filemanager.tpl